# Spring Security - authorize access early

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am wondering - you can deny access (user is already authenticated) *early*, without processing whole filter chain, can you do the same to grant access?

Currently I'am looking into voting mechanism (`AccessDecisionManager`, `AccessDecisionVoter`) but it seems impossible to implement such thing.

```
public class MyVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {
    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection collection) {
        var principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof MyUserDetails) {
            var myUser = (MyUser)principal;
            if(myUser.isAdmin()) {
                // stop further processing at this point, admin has access anywhere
                return ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        // could not decide - forward request to concrete, business logic evaluators
        return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        // no custom ConfigAttribute's - process all
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        // no customization for class - should process ALL requests
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here I presented only a dummy example, the rules for actually granting access are more complex but my idea is, hopefully, explained.

Comment: Why would you want to skip the processing of the remaning of the filter chain? Ideally a success authentication should go through the whole filter chain, because a filter may not just performing authentication/authorization, it can perform other things too - for example, the ConcurrentSessionFilter will invalidate concurrent session.

Comment: I have authentication configured to be ran before authorization. So I am sure filter order is in order (pun intended). I just want to break early when certain general criteria are met, like `isAdmin()` in the example.

Comment: I don't think that's possible due  to how filter chain works. And I still don't see why you want to do this. For the negligible performance gain?